# Outlook: [searchfromemail] missing in search result

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Outlook you can add a column (e.g. to your inbox) to display the sender address using `[SearchFromEmail]` (see e. g. question [1207793](https://superuser.com/questions/703013/outlook-how-to-display-sender-email-address-in-inbox/1207793)) by clicking **View** and then **Add column**. Now I want to replace the usual "From" column by a custom column (in order to help with identifying spam). `[SearchFromEmail]` of our internal emails do not contain a `@`, so in these cases I display the name instead using `[From]`:

```
IIf(InStr([SearchFromEmail],"@")>0,[SearchFromEmail],[From])
```

**Note:** Sadly you may have to localize the `[From]` variable. I e. g. have to replace it by `[Von]` which is in German.

At first this looked great, but then I noticed it does not work with emails in search results. For some reason those have no [SearchFromEmail]. (Thus my formula shows `[From]` which kind of bypasses my initial idea.)

Why is that and what can I do instead?

Is there a complete list of available Outlook formula fields?

**My (ugly) workaround is:**

1. if `[SearchFromEmail]` starts with "/O" I assume it is internal and show just the name
2. else if it contains a `@` then display `[SearchFromEmail]`
3. else display `"(?) "+[From])` as kind of a reminder or warning:

```
IIf(Left([SearchFromEmail],2)="/O",[From],IIf(InStr([SearchFromEmail],"@")>0,[SearchFromEmail],"(?) "+[From]))
```

**Note:** Sadly you may have to localize the `[From]` variable. I e. g. have to replace it by `[Von]` which is in German.

When I use the search function in Outlook, all results display my “(?)” warning. The relevant part of a screenshot (example):

[image: screenshot showing the result after doing a search in Outlook]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

[Use a formula in a Word or Outlook table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-formula-in-a-word-or-outlook-table-cbd0596e-ea8a-485e-a35d-b2cb2c4f3e27)

Comment: No, I am talking about the normal list view of emails (e.g. the inbox). There you can add custom columns (to replace e.g. the "From" column). One type of custom column is “formula”.

Comment: Do you mean the columns setting via View>View settings>Columns?

Comment: Yes, exactly. One click less with View > Add column.

Comment: Would you please provide a screenshot of it? (Please remember to hide your personal information)